# Uploading app with Google App Engine problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm trying to learn how to use the google app engine because I want to use stashboard (looks like an awesome tool) But anyway, I am following the hello world tutorial http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld.html and I wanted to try to deploy it. When I click on run in the GAE launcher I get this message in the log:

```
2010-12-09 13:52:42 Running command: "['C:\\Python31\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program       Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=',      '--port=8085', u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\pgoulet\\Desktop\\helloworld']"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 69, in <module>
 run_file(__file__, globals())
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 65, in run_file
execfile(script_path, globals_)
NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined
2010-12-09 13:52:42 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Then when I try in the web browser nothing happens. 
Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App engine support 2.5 or above versions of Python 2.x based versions , you use python 3.1 , download python 2.6 or 2.7 & it will work fine

Comment: GAE [supports Python 2.5](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html). If you want to be sure your code is compatible, you should develop it using 2.5 rather than 2.6 or 2.7.

Comment: strange enough i answer & get a negative response

Comment: can you close the Question please?

Comment: @Saif Probably because you said any 2.x version will work - only 2.5 is fully compatible.

Comment: @Saif You could probably edit your answer to be correct and the negative comments/votes would magically disappear (though it wasn't me)